# java.lang.ClassCastException String to JavaPoet.FieldSpec

Tags: java, java-stream, javapoet

I am using JavaPoet api for generating the source code. However, at some point I am fetching the require details from xml that is ready made string for creating fields then I save the string to Object and then I cast object to FieldSpec but it is giving me Exception. Is that I am casting it in wrong way?

```
public List<FieldSpec> getFieldSpec() throws JDOMException{
    try {
        fieldSpec = new ArrayList<FieldSpec>();//com.squareup.javapoet.FieldSpec
        SAXBuilder builder = new SAXBuilder();
        xmlFile = new File("CodeGenerationXML\\SourceCodeFieldsXML\\Fields.xml");
        doc = builder.build(xmlFile);
        RootXMLFields = doc.getRootElement();
        for(Element field:RootXMLFields.getChild("Fields").getChildren()){
            Object ElementField = field.getText();// returns FieldSpec.builder(String.class,"str").initializer("$S","Hello").addModifiers(Modifier.PRIVATE, Modifier.FINAL).build()
            fieldSpec.add((FieldSpec) ElementField);
        }
    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    return fieldSpec;
}
public static void main(String arg[]) throws JDOMException{
    new AddUpdateFieldsXML().getFieldSpec();
}
```

Exception:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.ClassCastException: java.lang.String cannot be cast to com.squareup.javapoet.FieldSpec
at RandD.AddUpdateFieldsXML.getFieldSpec(AddUpdateFieldsXML.java:94)
at RandD.AddUpdateFieldsXML.main(AddUpdateFieldsXML.java:103)
```

Comment: Check the return type of `Element.getText()`, seems like it's not returning what you think it is, but rather a `String`.

Comment: @BadCash, yes it is a string which I am getting from xml

Comment: There is no reason to declare the variable `ElementField` to have the type `Object` when `field.getText()` actually returns a `String`. If you declared the variable `ElementField` straight-forward as `String`, the compiler already told you at compile-time that the cast to `FieldSpec` is invalid.

Comment: Well there's your problem... You can't just cast a `String` to a `FieldSpec` and expect it to work. You have to somehow get that `String` into a `FieldSpec` object, probably by using `FieldSpec.builder()` (I'm not familiar with JavaPoet).

Comment: @BadCash, Yes you are right

Comment: Did you try something along the lines of `fieldSpec.add( FieldSpec.builder(String.class, field.getText()).initializer("$S","Hello").addModifiers(Modifier.PRIVATE, Modifier.FINAL).build() );`?

Comment: Yes, initially I have created class with required Fields `FieldSpec.builder(WebDriver.class,elementName).addModifiers(Modifier.PRIVATE).build();` but to make process fast and easy I have created the xml, so as soon as required field is passed in method in background I create xml with `FieldSpec.builder(WebDriver.class,elementName).addModifiers(Modifier.PRIVATE).build();` so that while create source I just read the xml and add the FieldSpec value from xml that is `FieldSpec fieldSpec = value as string gets from xml, which is then I add in list and pass it to create field method

Comment: `TypeSpec helloWorld = TypeSpec.classBuilder(className)
  .addModifiers(Modifier.PUBLIC, Modifier.FINAL)
  .addFields(fields)/* fields is List<FieldSpec> fields = new ArrayList<FieldSpec>();*/
  .addMethods(methods)
  .build();`

Answer (score 0):

Use the `builder` method like the example in the comment to create the `FieldSpec` object from the text in the XML element before adding it to the list.

Comment: I try with `fieldSpec.add((FieldSpec.Builder) ElementField);` but no luck.. Is this you are trying to explain?

Answer (score 0):

You can't just cast some object to a `FieldSpec` object. When you are using the `JavaPoet` API, you have to use `FieldSpec.builder` for every field you want to create. That's how the API works. See this [API](https://github.com/square/javapoet/blob/master/src/main/java/com/squareup/javapoet/FieldSpec.java).

Comment: do you mean `fieldSpec.add((FieldSpec.Builder) ElementField);` this?

Comment: Nope. `FieldSpec.Builder.build()` will give you a `FieldSpec` object. I have provided you the API link. You could have gone through that.

Comment: Thanks for your reply, I have already used `FieldSpec.builder(String.class,"str").initializer("$S","value").addModifiers(Modifier.PRIVATE, Modifier.FINAL).build()` which is working fine but now I am reading this from xml file which will return me read made format string that is "FieldSpec.builder(String.class,elementName).initializer("$S",elementValue).addModifiers(Modifier.PRIVATE, Modifier.FINAL).build()" and now I want to add whole this string to List<FieldSpec> as FieldSpec object

Answer (score 0):

As per your `Exception` log

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.ClassCastException: java.lang.String 
cannot be cast to com.squareup.javapoet.FieldSpec
```

this means there is no `IS-A` relationship of Class `com.squareup.javapoet.FieldSpec` to class `java.lang.String`. So, `String` value will not be assigned or cast to any non- varient type.

Here This code generate `Exception`

```
  Object ElementField = field.getText();// return String Values and Store it into the Object. 
  FieldSpec.builder(String.class,"str").initializer("$S","Hello").addModifiers(Modifier.PRIVATE, Modifier.FINAL).build()
            fieldSpec.add((FieldSpec) ElementField); // ElementField contains String Object.
```

Here, `field.getText();` getText() Method will return `String` Value and Store it into the Object which is **OK** because `Object` Class is parent of All Other Classes exists in Java .

Now, `(FieldSpec) ElementField` You are tring to cast String to a class `FieldSpec` which is not relevant to the java. Because There is no Relationship between `FieldSpec` and `String` Class.

So, `(FieldSpec) ElementField` this peice of code will raise the exception.

Comment: You should accept the answer if you got the answer.. Thanks